# Garbled laptop screen on 22.04

Tags: nvidia, screen, thinkpad, 22.04, screen-corruption

Ever since I installed 22.04 (Lenovo Thinkpad T480, Nvidia GeForce MX150, Linux kernel 5.15) in April I've been having episodes of my laptop display becoming garbled seemingly at random, every 1-2 days or so on average. It starts at the bottom of the screen and sweeps upwards until most of the screen is covered, then after a few seconds everything goes black. There may have been a faint buzzing sound once as well but hopefully I misheard.

Overall the system stays responsive, logging out with Ctrl+Alt+Delete or locking the screen works and restores the screen to normal. When the corruption starts while an external monitor is plugged in, only the laptop display is affected. I was lucky enough to get a photo of it as it happened last week: [Laptop display mid-corruption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaujW.jpg)

So far I've tried:

1. Moving from nouveau NVIDIA drivers to proprietary (nvidia-driver-510)
2. Switching between the Xorg and Wayland version on the login screen

I used to run Mint on this laptop a few years ago and I remember having had screen issues related to modesetting but wasn't able to find anything about it related to my current problems.

Thanks in advance and if any more info is needed I'd be glad to give it :)

Edit: I've ruled out hardware issues as I'm dual-booting Windows and haven't had any issues since the glitches started.

Edit 2: Going to list other things I've tried since posting here:

- running "sudo nvidia-xconfig"

Edit 3: I've asked the same question on Ubuntu Launchpad with some promising results, [link here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701901).

Comment: This should probably be a comment, but I can't do that. To me, this looks like a potential hardware problem. Is it possible to try another operating system like Windows and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Yes, I am actually dual-booting Windows on my laptop and I have no problems there, which is why I've ruled out hardware issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure it out on my own, I'm writing this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

My laptop has dual graphics and I noticed that on 22.04 LTS, the default nvidia prime profile activates the discrete GPU on demand.

After changing it to use the discrete GPU all the time I didn't even get graphical boot after restart, and in recovery mode I found an nvidia bug report file filled with errors. This would also explain the random nature of the graphical failures; they most likely happen whenever the nvidia GPU comes on.

Keeping the integrated Intel graphics on permanently seems to have solved my issue as I haven't had even mild glitches for the whole day.

Although this leaves me with no discrete graphics I'm considering this a solution for now, as I don't strictly need to do anything graphics-heavy on Ubuntu at the moment.